# NullPointerException when accessing 2D array

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

First, here is my function "setProduct" :

```
public void setProduct(String code, int qty,double price,int nbrProduct){

    System.out.println("Code = "+code);
    System.out.println("qty = "+qty);
    System.out.println("price = "+price);
    System.out.println("nbrProduct = "+nbrProduct);


    this.Produit[nbrProduct][0] = code;
    this.Produit[nbrProduct][1] = Integer.toString(qty);
    this.Produit[nbrProduct][2] = price+" €";
```

And now where I call :

```
Commande_Final Commande = new Commande_Final();
Commande = Cmd;

String name = Commande.getName();
double prixUnit = Function.GetMagPrice(radar,Qtyradar)/Qtyradar;

System.out.println("j'affiche le radar : "+name);
System.out.println("j'affiche le Qtyradar : "+Qtyradar);
System.out.println("j'affiche le prix du radar : "+prixUnit+" €");
System.out.println("nbr de produit = "+nbr_de_Produit);

Commande.setProduit(name,Qtyradar,prixUnit,nbr_de_Produit);
```

My problem :

I get an error when I do in "setProduct" =>     this.Produit[nbrProduct][0] = code;

The error says "java.lang.NullPointerException", I guess its trying to put an empty value in "this.Produit[nbrProduct][0]" but the thing is when I do the "System.out.println("Code = "+code);" its show me the correct code and the same for all others attributs :/

EDIT :

Here is how I create my Produit attribut :

public String[][] Produit = new String[99][3];

EDIT 2 :

stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Commande_Final.setProduit(Commande_Final.java:33)
at ZDialogInfo.Confirmer(ZDialogInfo.java:449)
at ZDialogV2$29.actionPerformed(ZDialogV2.java:1037)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code  (sorry I leave in french, then you see the real name I use):

```
public void Confirmer(boolean LoginCheck,String Nom,ZDialogInfo zInfo,final String Langue, Commande_Final Cmd) throws IOException{

                Commande_Final Commande = Cmd;

...

                if (Qtyradar > 0){

                    /*
                     * PROBLEME ICI
                     * 
                     * */
                    String name = Commande.showName();
                    double prixUnit = Function.GetMagPrice(radar,Qtyradar)/Qtyradar;

                    System.out.println("j'affiche le radar : "+name);
                    System.out.println("j'affiche le Qtyradar : "+Qtyradar);
                    System.out.println("j'affiche le prix du radar : "+prixUnit+" €");
                    System.out.println("nbr de produit = "+nbr_de_Produit);
```

/*ZDialogInfo.Confirmer(ZDialogInfo.java:449) => */

```
  Commande.setProduit(name,Qtyradar,prixUnit,nbr_de_Produit);

                    nbr_de_Produit++;
                    System.out.println("nbr de produit = "+nbr_de_Produit);


                JP_CNom.add(JL_CRadar);
                JP_CNom.add(JL_CQtyRadar);
                JP_CNom.add(JL_CPrixRadar);
                if (RnbrItem >= 1) JP_CNom.add(RCompo1);
                if (RnbrItem >= 2) JP_CNom.add(RCompo2);
                if (RnbrItem >= 3) JP_CNom.add(RCompo3);
                }
```

My public class Commande_Final

```
public class Commande_Final {
private String[][] Produit = new String[MAX_Produit][3];        
/*
 * 
 * [Nbr de Produit][0] = Code_Item
 * [Nbr de Produit][1] = Qty_Cmdé
 * [Nbr de Produit][2] = Prix_Unitaire
 *
 * */

public void setProduit(String code, int qty,double prix,int nbrProduit){

    System.out.println(" ------------------- Dans setProduit ---------------------- ");



    System.out.println("Code = "+code);
    System.out.println("qty = "+qty);
    System.out.println("prix = "+prix);
    System.out.println("nbrProduit = "+nbrProduit);


/*at Commande_Final.setProduit(Commande_Final.java:33) =>*/     this.Produit[nbrProduit][0] = code;
    this.Produit[nbrProduit][1] = Integer.toString(qty);
    this.Produit[nbrProduit][2] = prix+"";

}
```

Comment: Try to print this.Produit[nbrProduct][0] and 'this.Produit`, you'll find the source of error.

Comment: Can you post how you initialized your 2D array?

Comment: public String[][] Produit = new String[MAX_Produit][3];  where MAX_Product = 99

Comment: does nbrProduct have value??

Comment: @D3fman you initialized it well. are you sure the NPE is there? Can you post the stack trace please?

Comment: @ Eves Mary: yes and its zero.

Comment: @Joffrey : what do you mean by NPE ?

Comment: @D3fman Sorry, it means `NullPointerException`, please post the full stack trace. Btw, you mixed french and english with your method declaration VS your method call

Comment: @EvesMary I guess the OP is just translating his code for us SO users to understand, the code might be only French on his computer.

Comment: I think its an NPE : "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: No the error doens't come from name attribution, I just changed when i posted here bcz it was in french.

Comment: @D3fman The "stack trace" means the list of method calls and line numbers below the line that you posted here. Please post the whole thing in your question. Also, how is `Cmd` declared/initialized in your `main`. Please provide more code.

Comment: ohh..ok..What do you mean by Commande = Cmd;? are you trying to set the values of the object cmd to commande?

Comment: Can you check EDIT 2 plz, thanks

Comment: @D3fman The stack trace is not your code, it is the error. The full text of the error. You don't have just `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` do you? There should be some stuff below. Look at @PabloLozano's answer for an example of stack trace.

Comment: @Joffrey : Ok I have puted the full stack trace.

Comment: @D3fman That's great. Now read the different answers to see if something helps you. People have edited their answers now that they now what's going on.

Comment: @D3fman the problem is likely to come from some parts of the code that are not posted, please post all relevant code interacting with the `Produit` attribute. If there is no need for this attribute to be `public`, make it `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

According to your stack trace, NPE is caused by this line:

```
this.Produit[nbrProduct][0] = code;
```

Apparently, you found out via console output that what is `null` here is `this.Produit`.

### Possible Cause

Since you said you initialized `Produit` with the following line:

```
private String[][] Produit = new String[99][3];
```

then your NPE should not happen, unless you have reset the reference to `null` somewhere via some code like:

```
Commande.Produit = null;
```

#### Finding write accesses

If you're using Eclipse, there is a way to find every write access to your attribute:

1. click on your attribute `Produit` in your `Commande_Final` class, so that it is highlighted
2. go to `Search > Write Access > Project`
3. check if there is any other write access than your initialization

Comment: Thats the problem, I never do that and no where else I access to Commande.Produit[][] directly, only by the function setProduit().

Comment: Yes it is and it change nothing.

Comment: @D3fman If you're using Eclipse, click on your attribute `Produit` in your `Commande_Final` class, so that it is highlighted. Then go to `Search > Write Access > Project` and check if there is any other write access than your initialization.

Comment: OMG :o Thank you soo much, it was my fault. In fact, I was doing an overwrite on Produit[][] -_- Really sorry for that, but thanks for the "Search" tip, I will use it more often I think ^^

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you haven't set up the array correctly.

A simplest example:

```
Foo[] foo = new Foo[10];
```

it is just making an array with 10 reference to Foo, however there is no actual Foo object those reference is pointing to.  Hence it will cause NPE when you are trying to access `foo[0].bar()`

Similar,

```
Product[][] product = new Product[10][];
```

is going to give u an array of 10 reference pointing to Product[].  However there is no actual Product array object created.  Therefore similar to the above example, you will get NPE if you do `product[1][0]`, because `product[1]` is point to null, NPE is thrown because you want to access `[0]` of that null `Product[]` reference.  You need to instantiate them explicitly.

---

Update:

With the extra code that OP quoted, I have tried to run that and there is no NPE from that piece of code.

It is most probably that, you have reassigned your `produit` (I would strongly recommend you follow Java's common naming convention) to `null`, or assigned `produit[n]` to null in some other code.

I would suggest a quick check on which one is null:

Add before your assignment:

```
System.out.println("produit null ? " + (produit == null));
System.out.println("produit[n] null ? " + (produit[nbrProduit] == null));
```

it should tell you which one is null, and give you hints where you may have incorrect updated the reference.

Comment: This is wrong! You can't declare it like `new Product[][10];`. I think you mean `new Product[10][];`. And the first one doesn't face the real problem. With your first example you can access it like `foo = new Foo();` It's how you have to write `this.Produit[nbrProduct] = new String[X];`.

Comment: oops, my fault of writing `Product[][10]` instead of `new Product[10][];`  My first example simply demonstrate the case that : instantiating an array won't instantiate the object the array is pointing, hence, if you do foo[1].bar(), it will throw NPE, just like what OP is doing: `this.Produit[nbrProduit][1] ` he is accessing [1] of `this.Produit[nbrProduit]` which can be null.

Comment: updated the answer a bit to avoid misunderstanding @bobbel is having

Comment: Thanks! But the point is, that he don't want to access a method or variable on this object. He only wants to assign a new value on this specific idx in array.

Comment: that's why I said it may be `this.Produit[nbrProduit]` is null.  Please read clearly what I have written

Comment: Okay, i see... However... The problem has to be somewhere else since OP shows this part of code: `public String[][] Produit = new String[MAX_Produit][3];`. So there can't be a `NPE` if OP doesn't assign `Produit` new anywhere else.

Comment: I tried your code and I get for the 1st sysout => true and then for 2nd one i get an "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ZDialogInfo.Confirmer(ZDialogInfo.java:442)" where line 442 is your 2nd sysout. Its normal, sry i don't understand why you want me to do that ?

Comment: Then it is obvious that in somewhere else you have done something like `this.Produit = null;`  Find all location that you have assigned value to `this.Produit` and check the logic

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `this.Produit[nbrProduct]` is `null`.

It can be initialized: `this.Produit[nbrProduct] = new String[someSize];`

Comment: Or even `this.Produit`.

Comment: Yes but that's more obvious. So I stick to my first guess ;-)

Comment: How I do it, isn't right ? => private String[][] Produit = new String[MAX_Produit][3];

Comment: I don't know. You re-assign ``Commande`` just after having initialized it.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning null never causes a NPE, the issue must be your array has been not initialized.

The array is initialized when the object is created, so my guess is that array is re-assigned before the setProduct method is called. Check if `this.Produit[nbrProduct]` is not null when setProduct is called.

PS: Please, use Java conventions: method, attribute and variable names start with lowcase, class/interface names start with uppercase. In general try to use CamelCase (except constants, that should be `LIKE_THIS_EXAMPLE`)

Comment: I updated with my full stack trace, sry for the Java convention, I will try to respect that.